# Mongoose - How to update multiple docs async

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update/create multiple documents at once with a query like so:

```
Follower.updateAsync(
   { organization: event.organization, user: { $each: userIds.map(userId => userId) } },
   { organization: event.organization, user: { $each: userIds.map(userId => userId) } },
   { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, multi: true },
);
```

However, in this example, `user` is an `ObjectId` and using `$each` only works for arrays, according to the Mongo documentation. Is there anything I can do to basically iterate over an array of ids and have it create/update everything at once here?

I know the entry will be created/updated if I do something like this, but I need to be able to do this for an array of usersIds:

```
Follower.updateAsync(
   { organization: event.organization, user: userIds[0]._id },
   { organization: event.organization, user: userIds[0]._id },
   { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, multi: true },
);
```